# Figure out this simple algorithm

Tags: algorithm

PSA: This is a homework question

It is required to draw two circles on the screen at two different positions.
Suppose one circle is drawn at `(100,200)` and the second is drawn at `(200,100)`.
If the radius of the first circle is given `80` and the radius of the circle is given as `70`, then the two circles will **intersect**. If the radius of the first circle is given as 80 and the radius of the second circle is given as 60 then the two circles will **not intersect**. Write an algorithm that will ask the user to enter the radii of the first and the second circle and display a proper message. Assume that the positions of the centers of the two circles are fixed.

Comment: So whats the problem? Just asking for code won't get you any help, as it's off-topic. Show us the code you've written and the problems you have with it.

Comment: I have no idea how to code it @Paul

Comment: split the problem up into smaller parts. E.g. reading the coordinates/radii from the user, calculating the distance of the centers of the two points and finally comparing the distance with the radii.

Answer (score 2):

It's your home task, and it's you who's supposed to implement it. That's why let me just show up the idea. If `{x1, y1, r1}` is the first circle and `{x2, y2, r2}` is the second one then

```
if ((x1 - x2) * (x1 - x2) + (y1 - y2) * (y1 - y2) == (r1 + r2) * (r1 + r2))
  // circles touch from outside
else if ((x1 - x2) * (x1 - x2) + (y1 - y2) * (y1 - y2) == (r1 - r2) * (r1 - r2))
  // circles touch from inside
else if ((x1 - x2) * (x1 - x2) + (y1 - y2) * (y1 - y2) > (r1 + r2) * (r1 + r2)) 
  // circles don't cross, they are separated
else if ((x1 - x2) * (x1 - x2) + (y1 - y2) * (y1 - y2) < (r1 - r2) * (r1 - r2)) 
  // circles don't cross, one circle is within the other 
  if (r1 < r2)
    // 1st circle is inside 2nd
  else 
    // 2nd circle is inside 1st
else
  // circles intersect
```

In your test case

```
x1 = 100
y1 = 200
r1 =  80

x2 = 200
y2 = 100
r2 =  70
```

the computation shows that

```
(x1 - x2) * (x1 - x2) + (y1 - y2) * (y1 - y2) ==
(100 - 200) * (100 - 200) + (200 - 100) * (200 - 100) == 
20000 

(r1 + r2) * (r1 + r2) ==
(70 + 80) * (70 + 80) == 
22500

(r1 - r2) * (r1 -r2) ==
 10 * 10 ==
100
```

we have **circles intersect** case